# Does a 500 Internal Server Error always mean web-server error?

Tags: http, http-response-codes, http-status-code-500

I have always experienced a 500 Internal Server Error to be a web-server error, subsequently logging it as a error.
However, I've been informed that a 500 Internal Server Error can be a *application* error as well. In this case, it does not seem to log to the web-server when this happens.

Are there cases where it is justified that a 500 Internal Server Error will *not* report the issue to the web-server error log?

www.w3.org reports:

> Internal Error 500
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: By "application error", do you mean client-side error (as opposed to server-side)?

Comment: Yes. For example if you are executing server side application code and your code throws an exception that you don't catch then the web server will treat that as a 500 error.

Comment: Actually, that clarification confuses the situation. Where is this exception happening? In a web browser? On the web server? In some system downstream from the web server?

Comment: It's a php forum called flarum. During install in a web browser, another user gets this error : http://i.imgur.com/anruidf.png (it mentions a 500 Internal Server Error). However, nothing is reported to the web-server. I would imagine this is server-side.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6), HTTP 5xx status codes are defined as *server-side* errors. Any client-side problem resulting in an HTTP 5xx error is an incorrect use of HTTP status codes. Client-side issues that prevent requests from being fulfilled should result in HTTP 4xx status codes.

> ### 6.6 Server Error 5xx
>
> The 5xx (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the requested method. ...

-- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6

> ### 6.5 Client Error 4xx
>
> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred. ...

-- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5

Comment: That is not the spec. What's relevant is RFC 7231.

Comment: RFC 7231 has near identical text to W3C. Updated links, quotes and section #s

Answer (score 0):

If you see the 500 error on a website which is running Microsoft IIS, you may get a more specific error message:

```
500.0   Module or ISAPI error occurred.
500.11  Application is shutting down on the web server.
500.12  Application is busy restarting on the web server.
500.13  Web server is too busy.
500.15  Direct requests for Global.asax are not allowed.
500.19  Configuration data is invalid.
500.21  Module not recognized.
500.22  An ASP.NET httpModules configuration does not apply in Managed Pipeline mode.
500.23  An ASP.NET httpHandlers configuration does not apply in Managed Pipeline mode.
500.24  An ASP.NET impersonation configuration does not apply in Managed Pipeline mode.
500.50  A rewrite error occurred during RQ_BEGIN_REQUEST notification handling. A configuration or inbound rule execution error occurred.
500.51  A rewrite error occurred during GL_PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST notification handling. A global configuration or global rule execution error occurred.
500.52  A rewrite error occurred during RQ_SEND_RESPONSE notification handling. An outbound rule execution occurred.
500.53  A rewrite error occurred during RQ_RELEASE_REQUEST_STATE notification handling. An outbound rule execution error occurred. The rule is configured to be executed before the output user cache gets updated.
500.100 Internal ASP error.
```

For Apache webserver you can check its log file `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

For IIS you can find log files in `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` or `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR`